# PHP openssl_sign() ecparam key type not supported in this PHP build

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature, elliptic-curve

`openssl_sign` is returning the signature string but printing this error. I am using elliptic curve key

```
Warning: openssl_sign() [function.openssl-sign]: key type not supported in this PHP build! in
```

Comment: I also see this behavior

Answer (score 0):

An issue has been filed in the php issue tracker for this:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66501